# IdentityServer4 - How is the API token being validated behind the scenes?

Tags: identityserver4

In IdentityServer4 [Protecting an API using Client Credentials](http://identityserver4.readthedocs.io/en/release/quickstarts/1_client_credentials.html) documentation it is written that:

> The job of that middleware is:
>
> - validate the incoming token to make sure it is coming from a trusted
>     issuer
> - validate that the token is valid to be used with this api (aka
>     scope)

I have an IdentityServer4 server running on port 5000 and my API is running on port 5001 (2 different servers). I'm wondering what happens behind the scenes in the API when a request comes in with the access token... Does the IdentityServer middleware in the API makes an http call to IdentityServer for each request coming in to the API to validate the token? Does it cahche the token in some way? What actually happen?

Comment: [Here is the source](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4.AccessTokenValidation)

Comment: [Here is the TokenValidator source for the server.](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4/blob/dev/src/IdentityServer4/Validation/TokenValidator.cs) The middleware just calls the Introspection endpoint.

Comment: @Carson - so it does make an http call for each request coming in?

Comment: Well, it tries to use the JwtBearerAuthentication middleware from Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer. If it cannot properly build the delegate needed to execute the validation middleware locally, then it calls to introspection. So if you have the proper configuration options it should be local, otherwise yes, it appears to call introspection each time. Maybe the introspection middleware has some caching, but I'm not sure.

Comment: [See this line for the configuration of the local validation](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4.AccessTokenValidation/blob/dev/src/IdentityServer4.AccessTokenValidation/IdentityServerAuthenticationMiddleware.cs#L41)

Comment: The code for the JwtBearer validation is [here](https://github.com/aspnet/Security/tree/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer)